# TinyTds - problems connecting to Azure SQL database using '@' in username

Tags: sql, ruby, azure, tiny-tds

I was given credentials to access an Azure SQL Database and am trying to connect via TinyTds:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'tiny_tds'
server = 'xxx.database.windows.net'
database = 'yyysqldb03'
username = 'firstname.lastname@company.onmicrosoft.com'
password = 'zzzz'
client = TinyTds::Client.new username: username, password: password, 
  host: server, port: 1433, database: database, azure: true
```

But I am always getting an error as it seems the username is interpreted as containing the DB server name after the '@', yet I am told I need to authenticate with this username (aka an Email address) as is:

```
ruby-2.5.1/gems/tiny_tds-2.1.1/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:60:in `connect':
 Cannot open server "company.onmicrosoft.com" requested by the login.The login failed. (TinyTds::Error)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: I was able to log in using SSMS 17 using the 'Active Directory - Password' as a login/authentication option. Now I am wondering if there is any way to log in using this method programatically (i.e. using TinyTDS) ?

Comment: Is that really your user name for the Azure DB? We utilize Azure for some of our MSSQL database needs but our user names are not email addresses (or email address like)